# how can i declare globally class object for all window form

Tags: c++

I have one class and some window forms, i want to create the object of that class which will be used in all window forms. Can anyone tell me the exact way of using global class object.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Comment: How do you think does it differ from using a global int?

Comment: if i have class object in window form then i can use all functions of that class , and the way of using global int is using "extern" keyword that way is not working in calling class object in window form.

Comment: Global variables (including singletons) are usually a bad idea and an indication of a bad design. It's usually better in the long run to declare such objects in `main()` where their lifetime is under control and then pass smart-pointers, raw pointers or references (depending on the exact circumstances) to other objects that need access to the object.

Comment: @JesperJuhl - In theory I would agree with you. But in practice ....

Comment: @Ed Heal In practice I've seen globals/singletons cause too many problems in large code bases. You end up with too tightly coupled components, you end up with destructors running after `main` ends which sometimes causes problems, you end up with problems due to undefined instantiation order, and much more.

Comment: @JesperJuhl - I think they should be used with caution. Granted. But they do have a use. Use with due diligence.

Comment: _that way is not working in calling class object in window form_ that’s wrong

Comment: @JesperJuhl I usually keep global access (for convenience) but ditch static lifetime, either by updating a global pointer to the object on the stack, or by using a global `std::optional` and using a RAII hook inside `main` for its lifetime.

Comment: @manni66 yea that way is working, you are right but now can you tell me how can i get the object of window form class in custom class, i already include the name of window form class `#include "Display.h"`  in custom class but when i create object like `Display disp;` then it show me error "identifier Display is undefined"

Answer (score 0):

it depended by your solution architecture, but in common cause:
in .h:
*extern YourClassName class_inst;*
in .cpp
*YourClassName class_inst;*